# Can I get Date in Java as TYPED INTO excel cell?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I have a java program that uses apache-poi 3.17 to read and edit xlsx workbooks.  I am trying to read a date, and the format is important.  I need the original date the way the person who made the workbook typed it in.  I've researched a lot and found that dates are stored as integers in Excel, with decimal numbers being the time.  So, for example, a person types in "1/1/1947" and Excel stores it internally as "17168", then displays it in the cell as "01-Jan-47".  I cannot change the original workbook.  Is there a way to get that original "1/1/1947" that was typed in while using apache poi in a java program?  When I do:

`Cell cell = row.getCell(cellColumn, MissingCellPolicy.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK);
String value = dataFormatter.formatCellValue(cell);`

The value comes out as the display value, "01-Jan-47".  When I do:

`Cell cell = row.getCell(cellColumn, MissingCellPolicy.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK);
cell.setCellType(CellType.STRING);
String value = cell.getStringCellValue();`

I get the internal value "17168".  Does anyone know how (or if it's possible) to get the original typed in value?  It is definitely stored in the Excel workbook because it displays when you click on the cell.  Alternatively, if I debug the program in Eclipse and click on the cell object shown above, the date shows in the display format but it has the full 4-digit year; "01-Jan-1947".  I would also be able to use that if the original format is not possible, so if anyone knows how to get that to a String, it would also help. Thanks.

Comment: Get a `java.util.Date` using [Cell.getDateCellValue](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html#getDateCellValue--) and then do formatting that `Date` as needed?

Comment: If you are getting the string value `"01-Jan-47"` with the second snippet of code above, why not write a function to split it by `-`'s and do some string manip to return the original?

Comment: "It is definitely stored in the Excel workbook because it displays when you click on the cell.": No, it is definitely **not** stored. Stored is the numeric date value together with the date format. What you see in edit mode in the cell or in editor bar is the representation of that numeric date value in the operating system's default short date format. My German Excel would show `01.01.1947`.

Comment: Axel Richter, thank you I didn't know that.  That changes my thoughts on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained in comments by Axel Richter, the original format is never stored. What I thought was the original format is actually the default format for my OS.  I will use either the numerically stored format from Excel, or the Cell.getDateCellValue to get the full date and reformat it.  Thanks for the comments everyone.

Answer (score 0):

(following up on the comment)

Based off of this code you included:

```
Cell cell = row.getCell(cellColumn, MissingCellPolicy.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK);
cell.setCellType(CellType.STRING);
String value = cell.getStringCellValue();
```

Here is an example of a function that can return a manipulated String value to represent the goal that you are looking for:

```
private static String returnOrig(String value) {

   String mth;
   String[] parts = value.split("-");
   String day = parts[0];

   if (day.substring(0,1).equals("0")) {
       day = day.substring(1,2);
   } 

   switch(parts[1]) {
       case "Jan": mth = "1"; break;
       case "Feb": mth = "2"; break;
       case "Mar": mth = "3"; break;
       case "Apr": mth = "4"; break;
       case "May": mth = "5"; break;
       case "Jun": mth = "6"; break;
       case "Jul": mth = "7"; break;
       case "Aug": mth = "8"; break;
       case "Sep": mth = "9"; break;
       case "Oct": mth = "10"; break;
       case "Nov": mth = "11"; break;
       case "Dec": mth = "12"; break;
       default: mth = "0";
   }

   String original = mth + "/" + day + "/" + parts[2];

   return original;
 }
```

Which returns:

> "1/1/47"

Answer (score 0):

I remember trying the same.

```
Cell cell = ...
int format = cell.getCellStyle().getDataFormat();
String formatPattern = cell.getCellStyle().getDataFormatString(); // ddmm
```

Now the `formatPattern` might help to convert it to a java date formatter.
(The `format` code numbers some standard values (with constants in the API), and custom ones.)
At the time I refrained from doing so, as the solution was unsatisfactory.

Maybe you have more success, so I mention it.